# Laravel looking for singular table name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

when I send data from form to database

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fypp.joblisting' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `joblisting` where `email` = )
```

this error occurs.  In my database joblistings table exists but laravel looking for the singular name instead of the plural table name. Even I have created new model with new migration and everything but still facing this issue.

model code

```
class Joblisting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'category',
        'company',
        'email',
        'level',
        'number',
        'description',
    ];
}
```

controller code

```
class JoblistingController extends Controller
{
   public function showForm()
   {
     return view('frontend.pages.addjob');
   }
   public function createjob(Request $request)
   {
      $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=> 'required|string',
        'category'=> 'required',
        'company' =>'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:joblisting',
        'level' => 'required',
        'number' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
      ]);

        Joblisting::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'company'=> $request->company,
            'email'=> $request->email,
            'level'=> $request->level,
            'number'=> $request->number,
            'description'=> $request->description,
        ]);
        return redirect('viewlist')->with('success', 'job posted successfully');

   }
}
```

migration code

```
class CreateJoblistingsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('joblistings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->string('company');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('level');
            $table->string('number');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('joblistings');
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick fix would be define `$table = 'joblistings'` in your model

Answer (score 3):

You have to use like this

```
'email' => 'required|unique:joblistings',
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses snake case, hence:

Fix 1:
use controller name as `JobListingController`

Fix 2:
in your model, add tthe following line:

```php
protected $table = 'joblistings';
```